# Android Chrome - Html5-Video-Tag does not work with redirecting url

Tags: android, google-chrome, redirect, html5-video

Hi i have an hmtl5 page with an video tag

```
<video>
    <source src="medias/4eb5056e-c753-4aaf-ac56-4b643e2b9340/" type="video/mp4"></source>
</video>
```

The src-url will be redirected (302 Found) to something like

```
http://192.168.1.68/media.php?token=rHDgEhCmTs1QJexvjQA7&res=hi
```

This works in all desktop browsers. But now i tried it on android-chrome, and the player just does nothing.

If i change the src attribute to the right url it works

```
src="http://192.168.1.68/media.php?token=rHDgEhCmTs1QJexvjQA7&res=hi"
```

Any ideas what i can do? I need this redirect-mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the redirected url "medias/4eb5056e-c753-4aaf-ac56-4b643e2b9340/" needed authentication. But the Android video-player does not apply the browser's cookies to the request:

stackoverflow.com/questions/16310552/do-mobile-browsers-send-httponly-cookies-via-the-html5-audio-tag#16405325

even non-http-only cookies aren't applied on my phone (s4)

Comment: add a security-token to your urls to authenticate the video player